# Best markup for short stories on wiki-like site

Tags: html-parsing, ckeditor, wiki, markdown, markup

For a site where users can edit anything, what's the best markup to use for writing short stories?  [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/) is a good candidate editor for this and supports the following markups:

- Html
- BBcode
- Textile
- Markdown
- Wiki syntax
- Dotclear

This seems like a good list of the popular markups out there.  Which to choose?  Here are my thoughts:

- Html is the front-runner due to its ubiquitousness and, therefore, longevity.
- Markdown is a popular and attractive alternative to Html for simpler rich text writing like my needs.. maybe attractive because I'm used to it with SO?
- WYSIWYG editors like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com) often only work with Html.
- Because of the wiki nature, I want to show nice diff's. I imagine Markdown code looks a lot nicer diff'd than Html code. Alternatively, there are more likely existing libraries I could take advantage of to diff rendered Html.
- Links to pages within the site are special. Images should have their *current* description upon hovering and *current* caption, profiles should have as link text the *current* name, etc.
- I love that Markdown has limited functionality which is pretty much what a short story needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm publishing short stories on a Dotclear blog. Speaking of experience, I think that Dotclear markup is great but not adapted for one huge reason: it ignores "enter", you have to write "%%%" to force a new line, which is especially painful in dialog.

When writing, you want to think on the writing itself, not the markup. Most of stories don't use any markup at all. A few italic from time to time, a title, that's all.

My advice would be: take an existing story, convert it to the markup and take the one with less stuffs in the body of the text.

Comment: I don't understand your advice, would you mind clarifying?  maybe with an example?  The stories I want users to add include photos and very basic markup like italics, bold, links, maybe sub/superscript, etc.

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken. I thought you were talking about "short stories" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_story ). In your case, I guess it heavily depends on your users and what they are comfortable with. Dotclear is a very good markup for such usecase (I found it to be one of the easiest) but, unfortunately, it is not very popular, your users might already know some others.